# Relative path in Ajax works differently in different environment

Tags: javascript, java, relative-path

It is a SpringBoot website. The html page url is http://xxxxx/trex/index/ And javascript code segment in index page as below

```
$(function(){

jQuery.ajax({
    contentType:'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    type: "POST",
    url: "getSignTypes",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
            if(data !== 'NA'){
                console.log(data);
                $('#signType').combobox({
                    valueField:'id',
                    textField:'title',
                    editable:false,
                    data:data,
                    value:data[0].id
                });
            }
    },
    error:function(msg){
        console.log(msg)
    }
});
})
```

You can see I use relative path in url parameter of this ajax request. I guess since it is relative url, it should be converted into http://xxxxx/trex/index/getSignTypes. I test it in my local, and yes, it is as expected http://localhost:8088/trex/index/getSignTypes.

But when I deploy it to UAT, I find that the url is converted to http://hswcfc-trainexp-web.uat.homecreditcfc.cn/trex/getSignTypes. The index part is gone.

Why relative path in Ajax works differently in different environment? The ajax code is exactly the same. Any clue I can trace to find the difference? Thanks.

I past the UAT screen shot here.
[image]

Comment: The relative URL is always, _always_, relative to the current URL. The difference you are reporting cannot come from code, only URL has any impact (and code indirectly only in as much as it influences the URL). You must have not been on `http://hswcfc-trainexp-web.uat.homecreditcfc.cn/trex/index/` when your AJAX request was launched.

Comment: Hi @Amadan, what do you mean by 'AJAX request was launched'? The javascript code is in index web page, so I guess 'index' is where AJAX is launched. Do I miss something?

Comment: All I am saying is - check the URL. Pay extra attention to whether or not there is a slash at the end.

Comment: @Amadan. Thanks. I past the UAT screenshot here. The refer address of this ajax request is http://hswcfc-trainexp-web.uat.homecreditcfc.cn/trex/index. So I think index is where ajax is launched. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP URL consists of several parts: protocol, hostname, port, username, password, path, query string (`?....`) and fragment (`#....`).

As suspected, your URL *path* ends in `/` in dev, but not in UAT. Think of it as "directories": `/trex/index/` is the empty file name in `/trex/index` directory, while `/trex/index` is the file `index` in `/trex` directory. Web servers often treat the two the same way, but clients do not: when you do a relative path from there, you get `/trex/index/getSignTypes` in the first case, but `/trex/getSignTypes` in the second.

This is usually fixed by creating a redirect rule so that you can never accidentally write the same URL in two different ways (e.g. by redirect `/trex/index` to `/trex/index/`).

Comment: Thank you very much Amadan. Then it is clear. My problem resovled.